# JavaScript Button says [object HTMLButtonElement]

Tags: javascript, html, function, object, element

Here is my code:

```
var newRow = tableRef.insertRow(tableRef.rows.length);

var newCell0 = newRow.insertCell(0);
var newCell1 = newRow.insertCell(1);
var newCell2 = newRow.insertCell(2);
var newCell3 = newRow.insertCell(3);
var newCell4 = newRow.insertCell(4);
var newCell5 = newRow.insertCell(5);

newCell0.innerHTML = name.value;
newCell1.innerHTML = index.value;
newCell2.innerHTML = phonenum.value;
newCell3.innerHTML = grade.value;
newCell4.innerHTML = session.value;

var btn1 = document.createElement("BUTTON");
var btn2 = document.createElement("BUTTON");

var t1 = document.createTextNode("Confirm");
var t2 = document.createTextNode("Revert");

btn1.appendChild(t1);
btn2.appendChild(t2);
btn1.setAttribute('onclick', 'confirm(this);');
newCell5.appendChild(btn1);
btn2.setAttribute('onclick', 'revert(this);');
newCell5.appendChild(btn2);

function confirm(o) {
    var tr = o.parentNode.parentNode;
    tr.style.backgroundColor = "green";
}
```

What is the problem when I click on the button confirm it says `[object HTMLButtonElement]`?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `when i click on the button confirm it says` ... what is *saying* that?

Comment: oh .. because `confirm(this)` is executing `window.confirm` most likely and the context of the `function confirm` means it's not overwriting `window.confirm`

Comment: On Chrome it says **[object HTMLButtonElement]** as an alert

Comment: it's not an alert, it's a confirm

Comment: try code that is a little more modern ... `btn1.addEventListener('click', function(e) { confirm(this);});`

Comment: does `revert` work? or do you get an error in the console when you click that button - it has to do with scope

Comment: It's okay now thank you!

Comment: I have another problem I need to make a Revert History list like this the index and the grade and this list will update itself whenever i click the Revert button(meaning to show what i deleted/reverted):

Revert History

• 175462 - grade 6 • 215656 - grade 8 • 329897 - grade 7 sorted and so on

Comment: well ... that's another problem

Answer (score 0):

I guess because `window.confirm` is a general function in JS to display a popup for a user to confirm or decline an action.

You may try declaring your function more explicitly, like putting it into an object, or rename it into something else, like `confirmSelection`.

Answer (score 0):

If you're unintentionally seeing a print out somewhere (console.log, alert, etc.) that says `[object HTMLButtonElement]` then you're probably trying to print a string but instead handing the print statement an object, which results in printing out the object's type in brackets. Like @Bravo said, there isn't enough context and code. It would be helpful to know what your desired results are. If you're trying to print information about the button, like it's label, you could add `.textContent` after the name of your button to see the text within its html tag.

Comment: Thanks for the reply i understand now what that means and my intention was when i click on the button the row changes into green but i fixed it, it works. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Confirm is a javascript function and your passing this. This in your scope is HTMLElement Object. Change your function and try again thanks.